# Percent of selected records - SQL

Tags: sql, select

I am trying to write SQL to determine two percentages. The issue is my percentages are being calculated against all the table entries in the RUN table. I want my percentages to be based on the "Sum" and "Count" of the selected records. I hope this makes sense.

```
SELECT
      TEST.TS_NAME /*Test.Test Name*/ AS "Test Name" ,
      Count(TEST.TS_NAME)   As "Executions" ,
      SUM(RUN.RN_DURATION) AS "Durtion Summary"  ,
      Round(((count(RUN.RN_TEST_ID)/(SELECT count(RUN.RN_TEST_ID) FROM RUN  )))*100,2)as "Execution Percentage" ,
      Round(((SUM(RUN.RN_DURATION)/(SELECT SUM(RUN.RN_DURATION) FROM RUN)))*100,2)as "Duration Percentage"
FROM
      RUN INNER JOIN  TEST ON RUN.RN_TEST_ID =  TEST.TS_TEST_ID
WHERE
       TEST.TS_TYPE = 'QUICKTEST_TEST' AND  (TEST.TS_NAME Not Like 'FIN - Revenue Consignment%' AND  TEST.TS_NAME NOT LIKE 'WMIM - 053 ZIGO POSTO - Type UB, ZUS, ZM, ZP ZS - Test Case 49')

group by  TEST.TS_NAME
having count(TEST.TS_NAME) > 1
Order by "Duration Percentage" DESC, "Execution Percentage" DESC
```

Comment: Consider to provide sample data and desired output based on it to illustrate your question

Comment: place the COUNT & SUM inside the FROM, and use them for the precentral calculation

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solver this with the use of "over()" in my percentage calculations